# Removing HyperlinkedDefinitionSymbol's in a generated cell?

Tags: string-manipulation, cells

Is there a way to print out the definitions of a symbol with GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitionsLocal without any hyperlinks (just the plain text of it in the code cell)?

```
<<GeneralUtilities`
PrintDefinitionsLocal@PrintDefinitionsLocal
```

[image]